# Where is the “Test Login Needed” in App review in Google Play?

Tags: google-play

I recently uploaded a new app in the google play console to review, then I was receive an email that say:

> Please provide login credentials to the support team before you submit
>   any updated version for another review (select “Test Login Needed” and
>   include the test login account and password details in the open box
>   field).

I can´t find the “Test Login Needed” to select it.

Can anybody tell where is this option?

Answer (score 2):

- Sign in to your Play Console.
- At the bottom of the navigation bar, find the section "Policy" and click on "App Content".
- Start the "Target audience and content" questionnaire, or select "Start Again" if you already submitted.
- In step 2 "App Details" choose "All or some functionality is restricted" under "Instructions for app access".
- Enter the test login credentials there for app review team to access.